# How to set the domain for a view using python file?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

My exact requirement is, i want to set an extra domain in tree view, but that domain filter should not be applied for Calendar view?
I tried using "fields_view_get" but only context in can control using it, but not domain of the View. So, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO that design goes against the natural way views work.
Having a Model recordset, the several view types are expected to be just different presentations for the same record list.

In particular, the `<search>` view type and it's selections creates a domain for the current recordset, applicable to all other view types.

I suggest thinking of an alternative design, like using two different menu items for the two views.
Another idea would be to use CSS to hide unwanted records from the Tree list, but that means extending the client and needs that specific expertise.

Comment: But this has been set on Add Purchase Order field in Vendor bills right? And I tried figuring out how it's been done through the code but couldn't get to the bottom of this. Do you know anything about how it's been implemented in that field?